# KoaJS ctx.redirect() causing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS in Chrome

Tags: javascript, redirect, koa2

I'm new to KoaJS. Playing a bit now. I'm trying to redirect all request to a particular URL using a middle-ware. This seems to product `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` in Chrome. I tried a lot to debug. Can't get what is wrong.

**index.js**

```
// App
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()

// Parser
const bodyParser = require('koa-body')
app.use(bodyParser())

// Session
const session = require('koa-session')
app.keys = ['asdfasdf@#$ASDf1#$@5rasdf']
app.use(session(app))
// THIS MIDDLEWARE
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.session.user = '121' // This is all playground. No production stuff.
    const s = ctx.session.user
    if (s != '1213') {
        ctx.redirect('/login')
    }
    await next()
})

// Router
const common = require('./routes')
app.use(common.routes())

// Server
app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000') })
```

**routes.js**

```
const Router = require('koa-router')
const router = new Router()

// const User = require('./user')

router.get('/', async ctx => {
    ctx.body = 'Home Page'
})

router.get('/login', async ctx => {
    ctx.body = 'Login Page'
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Setting ``ctx.url = '/login'`` seems to work. Don't think it is the proper way.

Comment: You're setting the session value to "121" but subsequently check for "1213".

Comment: @robertklep Yes, i am deliberately redirecting.

Comment: That's the problem, though: you're _always_ redirecting. Hence the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Comment: @robertklep Can you explain a bit. ``ctx.url = '/login'`` seems to redirect properly.

Comment: @robertklep Does ``ctx.redirect()`` makes fresh request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your middleware:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.session.user = '121' // This is all playground. No production stuff.
    const s = ctx.session.user
    if (s != '1213') {
        ctx.redirect('/login')
    }
    await next()
})
```

Because `s != '1213'` always evaluates to "true", `ctx.redirect('/login')` is executed *for every request*.

This will do two things:

- set the HTTP response code to 302, telling the browser to perform a redirect
- set the `Location` header to `/login`, telling the browser to location to redirect to

Considering that this happens for every request, you end up in a loop: a request to `/` is redirected to `/login`, which itself is redirected to `/login`, which is also redirected to `/login`, ad infinitum. At some point, the browser gives up and issues a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

FWIW, after calling `ctx.redirect()`, you typically end the request, for instance like this:

```
if (s != '1213') {
    return ctx.redirect('/login')
}
```

In your case, you don't end the request, which means that it will be passed to the router.

To answer [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822794/koajs-ctx-redirect-causing-err-too-many-redirects-in-chrome?noredirect=1#comment90599837_51822794), I assume you used this:

```
if (s != '1213') {
    ctx.url = '/login';
}
```

You change the URL that the router will check to see which handler it should call. Sort of like an internal redirect, or a "rewrite": a request to `/` is handled *internally* as if it were a request for `/login`.

This is not something that you want though, because it may confuse the browser. The correct way is to issue a proper redirect, using `ctx.redirect()`, which will make the browser change the URL in the location bar and issue a new request.